# mypy generic subclass leads to incompatible types

Tags: python, generics, inheritance, mypy, invariance

I'm toying around with implementing monoids with type hinting. To that end I've written:

```
M = TypeVar('M')

class Monoid(Generic[M]):
    ...
    def append(self, m: 'Monoid[M]') -> 'Monoid[M]':
        raise NotImplementedError()
```

When using this in a subclass, e.g

```
A = TypeVar('A')

class List(Monoid[A], Generic[A]):
    def __init__(self, *values: A) -> None:
        self._values = tuple(values)
    ...
    def append(self, m: 'List[A]') -> 'List[A]':
        return List(*(self.values + m.values))
```

I get `error: Argument 1 of "append" incompatible with supertype "Monoid"`. Since `List` is a proper subclass of `Monoid`, I would expect this to be able to type. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, your `List` class *isn't* a proper subtype of Monoid. After all, you stated that all Monoids must have an append method that can accept any arbitrary Monoid or subclass of Monoid -- so, why is it ok to narrow List so that its `append` can accept only specifically List?

It's a violation of the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

You can work around this specific case by using a [generic self](http://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generics.html#generic-methods-and-generic-self):

```
M = TypeVar('M')
T = TypeVar('T')

class Monoid(Generic[M]):
    ...
    def append(self: T, m: T) -> T:
        raise NotImplementedError()
```

Now, you're expressing that all subclasses of `Monoid` must implement an `append` method that accepts specifically whatever that subclass type is. With this new version of Monoid, your List class is now typesafe.

Comment: You can even give `T` an upper bound of `Monoid`: `T = TypeVar('T', bound='Monoid')`.